# list all the videos (from the photo library and the video app) into the uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, alassetslibrary, alasset, mpmediaquery

I want to list all the videos. Not just the videos in photo library, but also in the video app, including the movies, tv shows, music videos, etc into my app.

When I used ALAsset like this:

```
ALAsset *asset = [videoLibrary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
videoURL = [[asset defaultRepresentation] url];
[videoURLs addObject:videoURL];
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video %d", indexPath.row+1]];
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]]];
```

in the (UITableViewCell *)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, only the video in the photo library will show up. Is there a way to get all the types?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to retrive all the videos on your IOS devices, you can find the code for same  [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748673/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-video-files-in-iphone)

Comment: This does not pull videos from the Videos app.

Comment: it will fetch all the videos from Photo Gallery (iPod Library) only, not from other Apps.- Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

```
    NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Process assets
    void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if (result != nil) {   
           if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo]){
                [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];
                NSURL *url = result.defaultRepresentation.url;
                [assetLibrary assetForURL:url
                              resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                                  if (asset) {
                                      @synchronized(assets) {
                                          [systemVideoArray addObject:asset];
                                          [self.mTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                             failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
                                 NSLog(@"operation was not successfull!");
                             }];
            }
        }
    };
```