# How to get url from video reference url

Tags: ios, iphone, assets

I have a url of video from photo library :-

```
/var/mobile/Applications/9BC2EBC4-7A71-4C8B-8BFB-D25D01E4CA83/Documents/IMG_5244.MOV
```

How can i get convert it to `NSData` I am tried following but nothing worked:

```
NSString* fileName = movieAsset.defaultRepresentation.filename;
                NSURL* fileUrl = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]lastObject]URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
                NSString *str = [fileUrl path];
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
                [arrVideoUrls addObject:fileUrl];
```

Comment: @paras, but i have already tried this.it is giving null NSData.

Comment: try to use normal video URL instead of absoluteURL

Comment: `videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[arrVideoUrl objectAtIndex:index]];`
i am using this even its not working.

Comment: can you post some more code for get that video URLs?

Comment: `if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypeVideo){
                NSString* url=[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
                [arrVideoUrls addObject:url];
}`

Comment: Try this code - NSData *dataVideo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str];

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code you have add `NSString` as an URL and try to convert that `NSString` URL to `NSData`, so here first convert that string url to `NSURL` and then convert it in to `NSData` like below...

```
NSString *strVideoURL = @"assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=2EBD925F-D275-403E-A6A4-3487134D9B9D&ext=MOV"; 
NSURL *urlVideo = [NSURL URLWithString:strVideoURL]; 
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlvideo]];
```

Comment: This is also not working . i have tried this as well

Comment: now try this code with your static URL and let me know if you will get response from this.

Comment: so here you need to provide whole code related to this video url or check these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585908/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-all-video-files-from-library-in-ios-sdk