# ios sdk list all videos in my video album (directory)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sdk

Can someone please detail a way to display all the videos in your library/directory or video album via UITableView?

I would like to basically list all the videos in a table.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585908/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-all-video-files-from-library-in-ios-sdk) may help you

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by @hima is talk about ALAssetFramework which is actually deprecated in ios9, use Photos framework.