# PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset for video

Tags: swift3, photosframework

i have an big problem with my situation

my main problem is i need fetch video one by one  do some operation on the video name and save it to the file system and again fetch another video do some operation on the video name and save it to the file system  through the loop of asset the problem is  completion handler prevent me do that because it saving all videos together without i do any editing and changing the name this save all videos i think it is working on background thread please any help to fix this problem i need handle fetch video one by one

this is my code

```
    for asset in arrayOfAssets {
        if asset.mediaType == .video {


               PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (AVAsset, AVAudio, info) in
                  // i need access to this place so i can fetch the video one by one and working with the AVAsset 

               })


        }else{
            let imageOp = PHImageRequestOptions()

            PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width:125,height:125), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: imageOp, resultHandler: { (img, info) in
               print(img!)
            })

        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

i think this one is related to your query 
for Vedios
[How Can i Get the List of all Video files from Library in ios sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585908/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-all-video-files-from-library-in-ios-sdk)

for Images
[Get all of the pictures from an iPhone photoLibrary in an array using AssetsLibrary framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr)

```html
allVideos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
 {
     if (group)
     {
         [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];
         [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
          {
              if (asset)
              {
                  dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                  ALAssetRepresentation *defaultRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                  NSString *uti = [defaultRepresentation UTI];
                  NSURL  *videoURL = [[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] valueForKey:uti];
                  NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video %d", arc4random()%100];
                  UIImage *image = [self imageFromVideoURL:videoURL];
                  [dic setValue:image forKey:@"image"];
                  [dic setValue:title forKey:@"name"];
                  [dic setValue:videoURL forKey:@"url"];
                  [`allVideos` addObject:dic];
              }
          }];
     else
     {
     }
 }
  failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
 }]; 

--------for ALL PHOTOS
 NSArray *imageArray;
 NSMutableArray *mutableArray;

-(void)getAllPhotosFromCamera
{
    imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
    mutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
    requestOptions.synchronous = true;
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];

    NSLog(@"%d",(int)result.count);

    PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[result count]];

    // assets contains PHAsset objects.

    __block UIImage *ima;
    for (PHAsset *asset in result) {
        // Do something with the asset

        [manager requestImageForAsset:asset
                           targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                          contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                              options:requestOptions
                        resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
                            ima = image;

                            [images addObject:ima];
                        }];


    }

    imageArray = [images copy];  // You can direct use NSMutuable Array images
}
```

Comment: yes Eric, but we can take idea from this.
and code can be converted to swift.
https://objectivec2swift.com/

Comment: but i don't need fetch all videos my friend i need to access between result handler

Comment: If it can be converted to Swift, do it yourself, please. // The same way we don't answer Java questions with Python answers, a Swift question should have answers in Swift...